# How do I find A in $y = Ax^2 + x + 7000$ (differential calculus, Leibniz's notation)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, physics, differential

So the problem I'm trying to solve is prefaced with this:

> Earlier we mentioned that NASA claims that the Vomit Comet can make passengers experience weightlessness for about 25 seconds. Let’s check on that claim.
> To simulate weightlessness (neutral buoyancy) the pilot must execute a parabolic flight path:
> $y = Ax^2 + Bx + C.$
> In Problem #88 you should have found that B and C were 1 and 7000,
> respectively, so the flight path is $y = Ax^2 + x + 7000$
> with A yet to be determined. The pilot will climb at an angle of 45◦
> to an altitude of about 7000 meters and then
> follow this parabolic path to produce a vertical acceleration of d
> $d^2y/dt^2 = −9.8 m/s^2$
> (matching the
> acceleration due to gravity) and horizontal acceleration of d
> 2x
> dt
> 2 = 0. This will provide neutral
> buoyancy inside the plane. On the way back down the pilot pulls out of this dive when the
> altitude returns to 7000 meters.
> For training purposes this is repeated 40 times.

And this is the problem itself:

> To determine A we need one more fact. At the beginning of the maneuver, the initial
> airspeed is about 180 meters/second (approximately 400 mph). Use this to determine dx/dt
> and in turn use this and the fact that $d^2y/dt^2$ = −9.8 to determine A.

The solution is $A = -9.8 / 180^2$.

I think I am confused about some of the concepts involved in solving this problem, which are detailed here along with things I know:

- I'm not sure how to achieve the "speed" of things in calculus. I am used to velocity, which you find by taking the derivative of whatever you're working with, and acceleration is found with the second derivative. So, how is speed calculated?
- I understand that airspeed is the sum of windspeed and groundspeed. In order to visualize this, I drew a right triangle with  the airspeed being the diagonal (which in this case I believe is curved, so I guess it's technically not a right triangle, but for simplicity's sake this is what I used), the bottom being the groundspeed ($dx/dt$) , and the side being the windspeed ($dy/dt$). I am guessing in order to solve this I would need to utilize Pythagorean's theorem, $a^2+b^2=c^2$, which in this problem is $180^2 = a^2 + b^2$. What I don't understand about this is how is this relevant to finding A?
- From what I understand, A is supposed to represent how wide the parabola is.
- This is what I did to determine $dx/dt$:

  > $dy = 2Axdx + dx$

  > $dx = dy/2Ax+1$

  > $dx/dt = 1/(2Ax+1)$

  I don't understand how I would use this and the fact that $d^2y/dt^2 = −9.8 m/s^2$ to solve for A.

Comment: Math is case sensitive. There is no $A$ in $y=ax^2+x+7000$.

Comment: Is there only air speed? How does Vomit Comet go?

Comment: @JohnDouma fixed it :)